# User.is_authonticated returns false in sign in page exceptionally django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

There are list of menus in base html, Home Download ... Sign in. The sign in menu should replaced by username if user is signed in. It working except the sign in menu itself. I tried to print the status of user sign in and it never shows that user is signed in.

Code of base.html

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ home }} " href="{% url 'home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ download }}" href="{% url 'download' %}">Download</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ highScore }}" href="{% url 'highScore' %}">High Score</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ about }}" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ user }}" href="{% url 'user' %}"> Hi {{ user.username }}</a>
  {% else %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ user }}" href="{% url 'user' %}">sign in</a>
  {% endif %} 
</div>
```

screenshot 1 shows username because user is signed in and user.is_authenticated  returned true
[image: screenshot 1 shows username in other menus]

screenshot 2: User is signed and user.is_authenticated returned false in this page that's why username is not being shown.
[image: screenshot 2 doesn't shows username]

Answer (score 1):

But django print the name in the first pic ... is that what you want ??

- you have a problem in DTL the code shoult be

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ user }}" href="{% url 'user' %}"> Hi {{ user.username }}</a>
  {% else %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link {{ user }}" href="{% url 'signinlink' %}">sign in</a>
  {% endif %}
```

and i can't understand why you use {{ user }} as html class

Comment: Sorry I couldn't explain the problem. Actually user authorized is always false in sign in page even after user is signed in. So when i go to any page except sign in page is_authorised works properly like if signed in then true else false.

Comment: for now there is only single page called user containing sign in/up codes. The problem is user.is_authorised() returns true false according to status in all pages except that user page.

Comment: ok I figured out the issue. I have passed dictionary which contains the key 'user' and this conflicts with the user.is_authenticated